# How to extract latitude and longitude pairs as a list from a LineString geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, coordinates, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    shape_id    geometry
    1000252     LINESTRING (4.91790 52.34725, 4.91797 52.34715...
    1000254     LINESTRING (4.80382 52.34495, 4.80413 52.34500...
    1000255     LINESTRING (4.89922 52.37811, 4.89923 52.37807...
```

With Python, I would like to extract the coordinates in the geometry column for each `shape_id` row individually as a list. For example, the output for `shape_id` = `1000252` should be as follows:

```
[[52.34725, 4.91790],
 [52.34715, 4.91797],
 [52.34742, 4.91723],
 [52.34752, 4.91713]]
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What’s the result you want? A list of lists of lists? Or you just want a method for doing this to a given row?

Comment: A method for doing this for each separate row

Answer (score 2):

Each shapely [`LineString`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#LineString) object has a `coords` attribute which give the points defining the linestring, and you can access the `xy` attr to convert the MultiPoint to a tuple of numpy arrays. A bit of extra numpy will get you to a stacked list of lists:

```py
# e.g. for position 40...
In [3]: np.vstack(gdf.iloc[40].geometry.coords.xy).T.tolist()
Out[3]:
[[0.7741171421283728, 1.715569328873729],
 [0.5852143769680165, 1.4516089839272017],
 [0.378452363108969, 1.2226445706965148],
 [0.43147551026039477, 0.7940308770193946],
 [0.3105453476502247, 0.770655256832471],
 [0.13440130471131118, 0.2957373776736154],
 [0.6793980801823408, 1.4291149753156192],
 [0.25803877234174954, 0.5296081932347322],
 [0.12773596566152468, 0.6238335508304359],
 [0.1575172393070674, 0.44929138014961945],
 [0.2222528104586241, 0.8623618596533595],
 [0.8185687868071416, 1.5897595726257494]]
```

See the shapely docs on [coordinate sequences](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#coordinate-sequences) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately thiscreates the coordinates in the wrong order (e.g. `[[4.91790, 52.34725], [4.91797, 52.34715], [4.91723, 52.34742], [4.91713, 52.34752]]`. Do you know how I can swap the coordinates within each pair?